# How can I block only one site with iptables if it shares the IP address with another site?

Tags: iptables

I'd like to use iptables to block YouTube. From where I am `nslookup www.youtube.com` returns (among others) the `172.217.21.110` IP address.

I don't want to block google docs, but `nslookup docs.google.com` *also* returns the `172.217.21.110` IP address, which is the same for YouTube.

Is there a way to block YouTube but not Google Docs?

Comment: Use a web proxy server.

Comment: You can't with iptables. It's that simple. You will either block too much (like your example), or block nothing if you get one of the other _many_ IPs for youtube servers.

Comment: @Lenniey There are other approaches such as using the `string` module. That would probably work better, but it won't be an exact match either.

Comment: @kasperd ah yeah I forgot about that of course. But as you said, won't be necessarily _good_.

Comment: @Lenniey Yes, for example it won't work if the string you are looking for crosses a packet boundary. And the string could show up for other reasons, so you could block unintended domains. If encrypted SNI takes off you'll be out of luck. ESNI is explicitly designed to prevent filtering based on domain name.

Comment: @kasperd - since the problem is generated by google rotating IP addressess (I think), would it be solved if I assigned specific addresses to www.google.com and www.youtube.com through dnsmasq? Would I create more trouble?

Comment: @simone Google change the resolution of their domains to send your requests to the data center which can give you the fastest and most reliable responses. If you hardcode the resolution of `www.google.com` on your own DNS server you can expect access to be slower and sometimes fail. You can try to block YouTube by forging DNS responses for the domain to cause resolution to either fail or point to incorrect IP addresses. But if you do that you can expect your users to switch to a DNS server which returns authentic answers rather than forgeries.